# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Scanning File to Byte Array

Tags: java

When writing byte array of file getting excetion like  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 512

```
returnValue=1;
File file = new File(filename);
    fileLength = file.length();

connect(servername);

private int connect(String host) throws IOException {
    int response = 0;
    if (socket == null) {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    return response;
}

byte[] b = convert();

private byte[] convert() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        long alength = 0;
        alength = file.length();
        bytes = new byte[(int) alength];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

    } catch (IOException io) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
    return bytes;
}

// Writing Byte Array

output.write(b,0,4);
  output.write(b, 4, ( (int) fileLength)); //exactly here i am facing error
```

Comment: Very stupid question: How large is the file? Could it be too large, resulting in a cut when casting alength to int?

Comment: Where in your code is the exception being thrown?

Comment: after output.write(b,0,4);  in catch block.

Comment: Might this line be executed?: return new byte[0]; That would result in an empty array, and you would not be able to write anythign (even just those few characters).

Comment: without casting to int how can i handle. byte array will accept only int types

Comment: The casting problem only occures for very large files. Arrays in java can only have an integer length. So if your file is too large, an array will not be enough. You won't be able to entirely load the file within.However this is only a problem, if the file is about 5GB or larger.

Comment: TreffnonX  It is not returning return new byte[0]. It returns byte array. but when that byte array write to output.write(b,0,4); it is throwing exception.

Comment: any suggestion??? TreffnonX

Comment: Does output.write(b, 0, ( (int) fileLength)); still produce the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
returnValue=1;
File file = new File(filename);
    fileLength = file.length();

connect(servername);

private int connect(String host) throws IOException {
    int response = 0;
    if (socket == null) {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    return response;
}

byte[] b = convert();

private byte[] convert() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        long alength = 0;
        alength = file.length();
        bytes = new byte[(int) alength];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

    } catch (IOException io) {
        output.write(b,0,4);
        return new byte[0];
    }
    return bytes;
}

// Writing Byte Array
  output.write(b, 4, ( (int) fileLength)); //exactly here i am facing error
```